# cod in codeblocks Mac OS

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I want to start learning C++. I use codeblocks and when i try to run my code, this appears in the Terminal:

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
'/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/mohamedasaad/Desktop/Giraffe/bin/Debug/Giraffe '
Mohameds-iMac:~ mohamedasaad$ '/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/mohamedasaad/Desktop/Giraffe/bin/Debug/Giraffe '
-bash: /Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/mohamedasaad/Desktop/Giraffe/bin/Debug/Giraffe : No such file or directory
Mohameds-iMac:~ mohamedasaad$

The code is:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Could anybody please help me with that?

Comment: The first warning ***The default interactive shell is now zsh.*** seems easy to fix given the instructions.

Comment: Your code is missing `#include <iostream>` at the top.

Comment: I have /bin/zsh as Login shell. When i try to run  chsh -s /bin/zsh  in my terminal, it asks me to enter my password and after i have done that, it says no changes made. 

I had included #include <iostream>.

Comment: How do you compile the program (if via code blocks, which icon do you click), how do you run it? Evidently, you did not compile the program. Most probably code::blocks installation is broken.